# How to run Stratum for terracoin?

Tags: asic, stratum

I have a few asic blades 13 GHs and I am farming BTC on slash pool via stratum.
How to change and what inside stratum to make those asics farm terarcoin on any one pool for TRC?

Comment: What do you mean by "inside stratum"?

Answer (score 0):

Stratum is dependent on the pool you are operating with.  First you need to find a pool that supports terracoin, a short list can be found at [terracon.org](http://terracoin.org/directory/).

Once you decide on a pool, read their "Help" section to find the server settings required.  I works exactly the same as bitcoin, you will enter a server address, a connection port, a username and a password.

Assuming you are using cgminer the parameters will look something like this:

```
cgminer -o http://pool:port -u username -p password
```

But plug in the values given from the pool.  Welcome to Stack Exchange and good luck!